# How to get value by only giving part of a name in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get an id from a query right now my table looks like this

```
id = 2000 name = 'johnson, bob' ssn='1234'
```

My login page asks for last name and ssn and then I use that info in a query to get their id.

Im trying to figure out how to write this query when the name field contains BOTH lastname, firstname. I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write query like this: customize name parameter like this before send it to query

```
string nameValue={name from ui}+",%";
```

SQL query:

```
Select id 
from {your table name}
where ssn={ssn value from ui} and name Like nameValue;
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I don't think that would work because what if they typed in "john"?  It would still work

Comment: if you type in john ,your namevalue will be ""john,%" ,so it wont get any results ..if you type in "johnson" then name value will be "johnson,%" and it will get 1 result

Comment: Right.  Forgot you had the string nameValue before that.  Hard for me to read when it is all in normal text.

Answer (score 1):

Besides LIKE you could also use [SUBSTR_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', 1) = 'johnson'
```

Of course you better normalize your table and store first and last name in different columns.